# What changes to put-call parity are necessary when evaluating american options on non-dividend paying assets?

Tags: options, put-call-parity

If an underlying doesn't pay dividends (for our purpose defined as any distribution to the underlying's holder) directly or indirectly (e.g. options on futures) how does put-call parity change from the usual assumption of a European option?

In particular, I'm thinking of bond options like the [10-year Treasury Note](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/us-treasury/10-year-us-treasury-note_contractSpecs_options.html).  Clearly options like these are worth more but how much more and what factors are required to evaluate put-call parity?

Answer (score 8):

In John Hull's *[Option's, Futures and Other Derivatives](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132777428)*, it states in the chapter "Properties of Stock Options" that from put-call parity, it follows for American options that
$$
S_0 - K \le C - P \le S_0 - K e^{-rT}
$$
where $C$ and $P$ are the American call and put prices.

In the book, the derivation is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 5):

There is an interesting article entitled [American Put Call Symmetry](http://www.math.nyu.edu/research/carrp/papers/pdf/apcs2.pdf) from the mid 90s that might be what you want.